# computing the sums of sequences with sigma

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm looking into solving the following [2 problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoa0l.png). I have recently gotten into sequences and am slow learning discrete math on my own time, I'm not sure how to go about these with sigma added in.
a. $\sum_{i = 1}^{2}\sum_{j = 1}^{3} (2i + j)$
b. Assume $S = \{3, 5, 8\}$, then $\sum_{i\in S}^{} (2i - 1)$

Comment: Hint: The result of b. is equal to the result of a., see the answer of Colbi.

Comment: Hint2: Colbi has used that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n\cdot (n+1)}{2}$

Comment: thank you again, i got the following result for b using the examples and hints provided by @colbi and you  https://imgur.com/ksXVQdr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will do the first for you.
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{3} 2i + j = \sum_{j = 1}^{3} 2i + \sum_{j = 1}^{3} j
=\left(2i\cdot3\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot3(3 + 1)\right) = 6i + 6$$
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{2} 6i + 6 = 6\sum_{i = 1}^{2} i + \sum_{i = 1}^{2} 6 = \left(6\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot2(2 + 1)\right) + \left(6\cdot2\right) = 30$$